# PostgreSQL: changing a column of enum type

Tags: postgresql, enums

This is the definition of the enumerated type:

```
CREATE TYPE khstate AS ENUM ('none', 'form', 'test', 'finished');
```

Now, in a database table I have a row with columns 'id' (type SERIAL) and 'state' (type khstate). The value of the 'id' column is 100004, and the value of the 'state' column is 'none'. How do I change it to, say, 'form'? The table definition is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS khs (  
    id SERIAL UNIQUE,  
    state khstate DEFAULT 'none',  
    PRIMARY KEY (id)  
);
```

I have tried queries such as

```
UPDATE tablename SET state = 'form' WHERE id = 100004;
```

ERROR:  invalid input value for enum khstate: "form"

```
UPDATE tablename SET state = 'form'::khstate WHERE id = 100004;
```

ERROR:  invalid input value for enum khstate: "form"

but without success. I am using the latest [BitNami LAPPstack](http://bitnami.org/stack/lappstack), so the version of PostgreSQL is 9.1.1.

I havent added any RULE or TRIGGER constraints, nor have I used transactions explicitly.

I tried to google for a solution, but all I could find were questions how to change the enum type itself, rather than the value of a column.

Comment: Both forms work here. Edit your question to include the the CREATE TABLE statement and the actual error message. (Copy and paste; don't retype.)

Comment: Curiosity - after executing your UPDATE statements, did you commit the transactions?

Comment: @BobJarvis: PostgreSQL runs in auto-commit mode by default. I quote from the [chapter "Transations" in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-transactions.html):`If you do not issue a BEGIN command, then each individual statement has an implicit BEGIN and (if successful) COMMIT wrapped around it.`

Comment: Among possible explanations: a `RULE` or `TRIGGER` preventing the update.

Comment: @tuope: which PostgreSQL version are you using? your example works for me with 9.1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: My above statement is correct as it is. **PostgreSQL itself** treats every command as its own transaction by default. What may be misleading here - I quote [the same chapter of the manual again](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-transactions.html): `Some client libraries issue BEGIN and COMMIT commands automatically, so that you might get the effect of transaction blocks without asking. Check the documentation for the interface you are using.`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: ok, thanks for the link. Seems I have mixed up some things...

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates that `'form'` is not a registered value for your enum type `khstate`.

I also notice that in your question you create a table named `khs`, but the UPDATE example uses `tablename` instead.

There may be a mixup of tables, schemas or databases. Diagnose your problem by running this query in the same session that gives you the error message:

```
SELECT enum_range(NULL::khstate)
```

Do you see `form` in the array of values? I expect, you don't.

More about [enum support functions in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-enum.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! I am extremely embarrassed that the 'form' value was not, indeed, listed among the array of values. I had made a typo. :-( Sorry for the "trouble".